# Discrete Fourier Transform seems to be printing incorrect answers?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am attempting to write a program that calculates the discrete fourier transform of a set of given data. I've sampled a sine wave, so my set is (pi/2,2*pi,3*pi/2,2*pi). Here is my program:

```
program DFT
implicit none
integer :: k, N, x, y, j, r, l
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
real, allocatable,dimension(:) :: h, rst
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: W
real(kind=dp) :: pi


open(unit=100, file="dft.dat",status='replace')

N = 4

allocate(h(N))
allocate(rst(N))
allocate(W(-N/2:N/2,1:N))

pi = 3.14159265359

do k=1,N
  h(k) = k*(pi*0.5)
end do


do j = -N/2,N/2
do k = 1, N

    W(j,k) = EXP((2.0_dp*pi*cmplx(0.0_dp,1.0_dp)*j*k)/N)

end do
end do

rst = matmul(W,h)
!print *, h, w
write(100,*) rst

end program
```

And this prints out the array rst as:

```
0.00000000  0.00000000  15.7079639  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

Using an online calculator, the results should be:

```
15.7+0j  -3.14+3.14j  -3.14+0j  -3.14-3.14j
```

I'm not sure why rst is 1 entry too long either.

Can anyone spot why it's printing out 0 for 3/4 of the results? I notice that 15.7 appears in both the actual answers and my result.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran does complex numbers for you but you must declare the appropriate variables as complex. Try

```
complex, allocatable,dimension(:) :: rst
complex, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: W
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question has been answered and accepted, the program given has so many problems that I had to say...

The input given is not a sine wave, it's a linear function of time. Kind of like a 1-based ramp input.

For DFTs the indices normally are considered to go from `0:N-1`, not `1:N`.

For `W` the Nyquist frequency is represented twice, as `-N/2` and `N/2`. Again it would have been normal to number the rows `0:N-1`, BTW, this is why you have an extra output in your `rst` vector.

`pi` is double precision but only initialized to 12 significant figures. It's hard to tell if there's a typo in your value of `pi` which is why many would use `4*atan(1.0_dp)` or `acos(-1.0_dp)`.

Notice that `h(N)` is actually going to end up as the zero time input, which is one reason the whole world indices DFT vectors from zero.

The expression `cmplx(0.0_dp,1.0_dp)` is sort of futile because the `CMPLX` intrinsic always returns a single precision result if the third optional `KIND=` argument is not present. As a complex literal, `(0.0_dp,1.0_dp)` would be double precision. However, you could as well use `(0,1)` because it's exactly representable in single precision and would be converted to double precision when it gets multiplied by the growing product on its left. Also `2.0_dp` could have been represented successfully as `2` with less clutter.

The expression `EXP((2.0_dp*pi*cmplx(0.0_dp,1.0_dp)*j*k)/N)` is appropriate for inverse DFT, disregarding normalization. Thus I would have written the whole thing more cleanly and correctly as `EXP(-2*pi*(0,1)*j*k/N)`. Then the output should have been directly comparable to what the online calculator printed out.